# GraphLab Create Installation Error - Python 3.5.2

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda, python-3.5, graphlab

[image]I have been trying to install GraphLab Create on my system (64bit, Windows 10).
I used the Installation guide as given on the site https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html
I used the command line since I already had Anaconda3 installed in my system.
I tried the Method - 1 but it didn't work because I'm not using Python2.7,  but Python3.5.2, so, I tried Method - 2 by using Virtual Environment.
I am getting a Syntax error when I try the command:

```
virtualenv gl-env
```

I have already installed Virtual Environment through pip so this should not happen, right ?
Please help me out on what could possibly be wrong.

Comment: Could we see the full traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the installation instructions [page](https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html):

> GraphLab Create installation requires a Python 2.7.x environment and pip version >= 7

You **have** to install GraphLab in a Python 2.7 environment, and not in a Python 3 one.
Thus, install python2 first and then follow the rest of the instructions:
`conda create -n gl-env python=2.7 anaconda=4.0.0`